# How can I get data of textview from one xml to another xml

Tags: android, xml

can someone help me about this one? I'm trying to build a simple quiz app that uses button, checkbox and textview. I want the score of all questions appear in the last page (5 pages) but can't make it work. I want to get the score from the previous question and then send it to the result page.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in SharedPreference and get the value in the last page and/or clear it depending on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the score from one activity to another using bundle in your intent.

> //From Activity A

```
//To pass data from one activity to another
Intent i=new Intent(context, MyTargetClass.class);
i.putExtra("somekey", scoreValue);
context.startActivity(i);
```

> //To Activity B

```
//To retrieve data from an activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
String scoreValue = intent.getStringExtra("someKey");
```

Comment: Gonna try this first.

Comment: Here is my code.
public void submitAnswers(View view) {
        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        Boolean answer3_choice1;
        Boolean answer3_choice2;
        Boolean answer3_choice3;
        c1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        c2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        c3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.choice3);
        answer3_choice1 = c1.isChecked();

Comment: answer3_choice2 = c2.isChecked();
        answer3_choice3 = c3.isChecked();
        if (!answer3_choice1 && answer3_choice3 && !answer3_choice2) {
            mScore = mScore + 1;
            updateScore(mScore);
        }
        else
            mScore = 0;
        }

private void updateScore(int point) {
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);